# onTouchEvent() causes "unfortunately app has stopped"

Tags: android, view, draw, touch-event

I am writing a game where you keep pressing the screen to let a helicopter fly. Now when the helicopter collides with the screen-borders (Hight & width of individual device) the activity finishes by

```
((Activity) context).finish();
```

It works perfectly fine when the player stops fastly after the collision, but if he holds on, I get the hated error.

Thant's why I suspect the onTouchEvent-method

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // background music
    mp.start();
    mp.setLooping(true);
    copter.setVolume((float) 0.2, (float) 0.2);
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && fuel > 0) {
        copter.start();
        copter.setLooping(true);
        if (!player.getPlaying()) {
            player.setPlaying(true);
            player.setUp(true);
            fuel--;
        } else {
            player.setUp(true);
            fuel--;
        }
        return true;
    }
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        copter.pause();
        player.setUp(false);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Is there some way to ignore TouchEvents after a collision? Or is the OnTouchEvent not even the problem?

Comment: No need to suspect anything. Go and look at your application log. There you will see exactly where crash happened.

Comment: please share the error stack trace from logcat

Answer (score 0):

Check if Activity is null inside `onTouchEvent()`

Here the code:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    Activity activity = getActivity();
    if(activity != null){
        // background music
        mp.start();
        mp.setLooping(true);
        copter.setVolume((float) 0.2, (float) 0.2);
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && fuel > 0) {
            copter.start();
            copter.setLooping(true);
            if (!player.getPlaying()) {
                player.setPlaying(true);
                player.setUp(true);
                fuel--;
            } else {
                player.setUp(true);
                fuel--;
            }
            return true;
        }
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            copter.pause();
            player.setUp(false);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
    //return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    return false;
}
```

Depending on your code you should use:

```
if(((Activity)context) != null){
```

instead of

```
Activity activity = getActivity();
if(activity != null){
```

If this is not the problem, please add the error stacktrace.

---

**Update**

To send stacktrace via e-mail:

```
Intent mailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
mailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"mail@gmail.com"});
mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
mailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, stacktraceText);
Intent mailChooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(mailIntent, "Title");

context.startActivity(mailChooserIntent);
```

Comment: The method getActivity() is undefined for the type GamePanel, so i used

Comment: GamePanel activity = GamePanel.this; instead

Comment: You can use the same you are using to finish the activity I supose: ((Activity) context)

Comment: done that, but get the same error unfortunately :(  thanks tho

Comment: Try it now, I changed the return logic. And please copy your error stacktrace

Comment: i am not using a virtual device, i send the apk via email, so i cant show any error stacktrace

Comment: Then you should use a device or virtual device to test it and see the stacktrace. If not you would implement a logic to ask user to send the stacktrace via e-mail or something